# Bootstrap block with 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code with Bootstrap 3.3.7:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navigation col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-8"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-8"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-8"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navigation has a smaller content height than items, so right after navigation it slides to the left ... How can you make the absolute height for navigation 100%?

Comment: that's all your code shows, even with `bootstrap` connected - https://ibb.co/LgLmj1K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach to prevent item sliding to left is to change layout design, initially dividing into navigation and item column and nesting items inside of item column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navigation col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="item col-lg-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to define extra row inside of `col-lg-8`, & its already full width covered for the item so no need to define `col-lg-12` in the item class.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia OP has been using class `col-lg-8` with `item` and we can't be sure if its not required without looking into actual design and requirements, further more usage of `lg` indicates a possibility of a responsive design so the intention was to fix the problem with minimal change in design.

Comment: no side effect in my way too because my suggestion is also work as you have done because there is also col-lg-8 at the parent in items so it manage responsiveness same as in your way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make changes in layout structure to fix your issue.

You know very well that in Bootstrap we have 12 columns in a row, now you are using `col-lg-4` at first and then use `col-lg-8` so total is `4 + 8 = 12`. now from the second `col-lg-8` it start from first and the again you are using `col-lg-8` means it can not adjust in the space after second `col-lg-8` in your code so third `col-lg-8` is also placed at the starting edge.

So now you have to make your grid structure like as provided below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navigation col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="item-list col-lg-8">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have given `min-height: 100vh` to *navigation* so it will take window height automatically. We also made `row` as flex layout so that if the `content-section` height increases then *navigation* height will remain equal to content-section.

Please refer to this link https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/mvkq17wn/18/

```css
.main-row { 
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.navigation {
   min-height: 100vh;
}

.content-section .item { 
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row main-row">
    <div class="navigation bg-primary col-lg-4">Navigation</div>
    <div class="content-section bg-info col-lg-8">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```